# How to remove a browser malware in google chrome Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, google-chrome, malware

Whenever I am opening Chrome I am redirected to **demo.opera-mini.net/public/** page. I google it and found most solutions related to registry config edit to remove it from Windows environment as they are saying its malware. How do I remove the same from my Google Chrome in Ubuntu 14.04 LTS.

Image -

[image]

Comment: Have you cleared cache? Also have a look at /etc/hosts

Comment: @Bruni Hosts file looks clean as it is containing info for my localhost and some info for IPv6 capable hosts

Comment: Just reset your browserit will probably solve issues.

Answer (score 2):

I hit the reset button and its gone now, not pretty sure if it really wiped out from my system, but its not prompting anymore.

[image]

This option is under **Settings** -> **Show advanced settings...**

Answer (score 1):

You probably installed some application/extension that have changed your startup Google Chrome tab.

You can change Google Chrome startup behavior in Google Chrome settings.

Open Google Chrome and, on the right of top bar, you can see an hamburger menu or 3-dot menu. Click on it and select Settings.

You should see *On startup* section as showed below:

[image]

Click on *Set pages*, from popup that it will open remove unwishied tab and add your preferred website.

For example I use google as startup tab.

[image]

**Update**

If this not work you could try to watch if there is strange extensions installed on your browser. To do this in Chrome type this in search bar:

```
chrome://extensions/
```

And look at your extensions. If there is something that you haven't installed, uninstall it.

Comment: This way the cause still persist as a ghost